# CSS - Fixing a box once scrolled to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out how to fix a red box on a mobile page once the user scrolls down to it.

The user can scroll down through the blue box but the red box will stay in position. Unless, the user scrolls to the top of the page, the red box will disappear.

The idea is the user is going to select activities to do (in the blue box) and a total cost for those activities will appear in the red box.

Comment: And what have you tried so far? Show your attempts.

Comment: Can you provide any code please?

Comment: Will do in future Oka and I didn't have enough rep to post an image moffeltje, thanks though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tec50Lkc/) which does what I think you want.

This is the javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).scroll(function(){
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() >= $('#blue').offset().top ){
            $('#red').show();
        }
        else{
            $('#red').hide();
        }
    });

});
```

And the css:

```
#red{
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 5px;
    top: 0px;
    display: none;
    width: 140px;
    padding: 5px;
}
#blue{
    height: 1200px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    margin-left: 150px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
}
```